# How to get the value of method arguments via @AroundInvoke in Quakus?

Tags: java, quarkus

```
    @AroundInvoke
    Object logInvocation(InvocationContext context) throws Exception {
        Method method = context.getMethod();
        String methodName = context.getMethod().getName();
        String genName = context.getMethod().toGenericString();
    
        // ...log before
        Object ret = context.proceed();
        // ...log after
        return ret;
    }
```

I want to use the `@AroundInvoke` of quarkus to record the method call log，which can be done through `AOP` in SpringBoot, but Quarkus makes me a little confused

How can I get the parameter values in the method?

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use the getParameters() method, check [this documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/interceptor/InvocationContext.html).

Comment: @JaveysWuu you are wellcome, this happens to everyone everytime